# wordpress get_users() function exclude or include with array of email address not with ids is it possible help me with this?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Here i have set of conditions :

1. roles in administrator,customer
2. user registered date between
3. include or exclude user emails

```
`$user_args = array();
 $user_args['date_query'] = array(
            'after' => '2023-3-1',
            'before' => '2023-3-10',
            'inclusive' => true,
        );
$user_args['role__in'] = array('customer','administrator');
$exlude_user_emails = array('test1@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com');//how to apply this i even tried meta query not getting expected user list
$wp_users = get_users($user_args);`
```

want exclude array of email data using get_users() function